# How to pass along an http Request in golang?

Tags: go, proxy, network-programming

I have a Request object in golang, and I would like to feed the contents of this object through a net.Conn as part of the task of a proxy.
I want to call something like

```
req, err := http.ReadRequest(bufio.NewReader(conn_to_client))
conn_to_remote_server.Write(... ? ... )
```

but I have no idea what I would be passing in as the arguments.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: For inspiration: https://github.com/elazarl/goproxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Negroni middleware. It let's you pass your HTTP request through different middleware and custom HandlerFuncs. 
Something like this:

```
   n := negroni.New(
        negroni.NewRecovery(),
        negroni.HandlerFunc(myMiddleware),
        negroni.NewLogger(),
        negroni.NewStatic(http.Dir("public")),
    )

...
...

func myMiddleware(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, next http.HandlerFunc) {
    log.Println("Logging on the way there...")

    if r.URL.Query().Get("password") == "secret123" {
        next(rw, r)      //**<--------passing the request to next middleware/func**
    } else {
        http.Error(rw, "Not Authorized", 401)
    }

    log.Println("Logging on the way back...")
}
```

Notice how `next(rw,r)` is used to pass along the HTTP request

If you don't want to use Negroni, you can always look at it's implementation on how it passes the HTTP request to another middleware.

It uses custom handler which looks something like:

```
handlerFunc func(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, next http.HandlerFunc)
```

Ref: https://gobridge.gitbooks.io/building-web-apps-with-go/content/en/middleware/index.html